# PrimeNG with Angular2-webpack-starter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angular, prime-ui, primeng

I'm trying to configure PrimeNG in my Angular2 project based on angular2-webpack-starter (https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).

I installed PrimeNG and PrimeUI using npm install, then added necessary typings as ambient dependencies:

```
"jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#470954c4f427e0805a2d633636a7c6aa7170def8",
"jqueryui": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts#a3a5cd5554dc2c0ff8955d1db0673879af3095bc",
"primeui": "github:primefaces/primeui/primeui.d.ts#7640bc59a3634e501634655217fdd413bed6d003",
```

Firstly I had a problem with jquery typing. It was giving me the following error:

```
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'.
```

I solved it by commenting out the following lines in `typings/browser/ambient/jquery/index.d.ts`:

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

Now I am trying to import `primeui-ng-all.min.js` within `vendor.ts` file using `import "primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js";` command. However I am getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery-ui' in .../angular2-webpack-starter/node_modules/primeui @ ./~/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js 8:23135-23167
```

Is it the correct way of including PrimeNG in angular2-webpack-starter? How should I solve this problem? And maybe how should I import other files required by PrimeNG, as i.e. stylesheets?

Comment: There is a PrimeNG+WebPack sample here. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-webpack

Comment: Here is a fork of angular2-webpack-starter that adds PrimeNG for the UI. https://github.com/cagataycivici/angular2-webpack-starter

Answer (score 1):

This is a **short** and **fast** way to get started(non-npm), firstly you need to download the components folders from here https://github.com/primefaces/primeng
then add this to your index.html add head

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prime/resources/primeui/themes/delta/theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prime/resources/icons/css/font-awesome.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prime/resources/css/prism.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prime/resources/css/fullcalendar.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prime/resources/css/quill.snow.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prime/resources/primeui/primeui-ng-all.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prime/resources/css/site.css"/>
<script src="prime/resources/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="prime/resources/js/prism.js"></script>
<script src="prime/resources/js/charts.min.js"></script>
<script src="prime/resources/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="prime/resources/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="prime/resources/js/site.js"></script>
<script>
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
            packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'},
                'components': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}, //Your downloaded components folder here.
                'prime/resources/js' : {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Check the paths before configuring the app.

Comment: To be honest, I prefer typical webpack/npm solution, especially in such a case, where most of the packages use CommonJS and starter provides both development and production builts.

Answer (score 0):

Manually installing JQuery UI through NPM and importing it in the vendor.ts (before Prime) fixed it for me.

```
import 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js';
```